# How to encode multiple items in a list when writing items to a csv file in scrapy

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, pipeline

I am new to scrapy, i scraped a web site and fetched all the required items and need to write them to csv file.

My `pipeline.py` code is

```
import csv

class example2Pipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.brandCategoryCsv = csv.writer(open('example.csv', 'wb'))
        self.brandCategoryCsv.writerow(['book_name','dimensions'])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.brandCategoryCsv.writerow([item['book_name'].encode('utf-8'),
                                    item['dimensions'].encode('utf-8'),
                                    ])
        return item
```

and the results of `xpath` code in `spider.py` file for the items mentioned above are

```
book_name = i.select('div[@class="slickwrap full"]/div[@id="bookstore_detail"]/div[@class="book_listing clearfix"]/div[@class="bookstore_right"]/div[@class="title_and_byline"]/p[@class="book_title"]/text()').extract()
Result : [u'Rahul']

dimensions = i.select('div[@class="slickwrap full"]/div[@id="bookstore_detail"]/div[@id="main_tab_group"]/div[@class="panes slickshadow"]/div[@class="pane clearfix"]/div[@class="clearfix"]/div[@class="about_author"]/div[@id="book_stats"]/p/a/text()')[0:2].extract()
Result: [u'Pocket',u'Science Fiction &amp; Fantasy',u' 26 pgs']
```

If u observed above for the `book_name` item there is only one item in the list so if we use book_name[0] we will be able to encode a string by the code i had written in `pipeline.py` file

But for the  `dimensions` item, we had multiple strings inside the list, so i am getting the following error when i run the above `pipeline.py` code

```
exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

That is we cannot encode a list, i am unable encode the individual elements in the list in `pipeline.py` file.

Also i want to write 1 item per column in a row in to a csv file like

```
book_name  |   dimensions

Pocket         Science Fiction &amp; Fantasy,  26 pgs
```

If u want additional code of my `spider` file i will paste here.

Any help would be appreciated,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have only have unicode strings in the list, try  " ".join(somelist), and encode or str it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try below..

```
(item['book_name']).encode('utf-8') ### make sure item['book_name'] is string/unicde becoz they(string/unicode) have encode method not list.
```

and for newline you may try..

```
self.brandCategoryCsv = csv.writer(open('example.csv', 'wb', newline=''))
```

To encode each item in list use below.

```
[i.encode('utf-8') for i in item['dimensions']]
```

Comment: Actually i am getting a list for dimensions item as mentioned above. By doing above i am getting same error, how can i loop through that list and encode individual string from that list in pipeline.py file. And also any other way to write items in to csv files. When i used new line it giving an error "TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: @shivakrishna see updated for `how can i loop through that list and encode individual string`

Answer (score 0):

Try **map** function of python

```
 def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.brandCategoryCsv.writerow([map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'), item['book_name']),
                                    map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'), item['dimensions']),
                                    ])
    return item
```